# How to add conditional formatting to PowerBi when I use line and stacked column chart?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to add a conditional formatting to the line and stacked column chart columns. I can add when I choose line and clustered column chart by using fx button. I could not this type of thing in line and stacked column chart.

How to add a conditional formatting to the  line and stacked column chart columns?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should find the `fx` button under the `Columns` section. I don't think you can for the Line though.

Comment: @SamNseir Thank you for your help. I generally do like this when I worked with "line and clustered column chart". When I looked for the other bar charts there is fx button, but there is no option for "line and stacked column chart" columns.

Comment: You should find the same in the "line and stacked column chart". Share a screen grab of what you are seeing (or not in this case).